# using cookies in angularjs 1.4.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm doing a simple "add to cart" system. I want the items in my basket to not disappear so I'm trying to use angularjs cookies. It works without adding cookie item, adding and removing ok.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap','ngCookies']);
app.controller('menusCtrl', ['$cookies',function($scope, $http,$cookies) {
   $http.get("getContent.php").success(function (response) {$scope.items = response.menus;});
   $scope.basketlist = [];
   $scope.updateCart = function (index) {
    var item = $scope.items[index];
    $scope.basketlist.push({quantity: 1, price: item.menu_price,no:item.menu_no,image:item.menu_img});
    $cookies.put("basketlist",$scope.basketlist);
   }
    $scope.remove = function(index) {
      var itemtodelete = $scope.basketlist.indexOf(index);
        $scope.basketlist.splice(index, 1);
    }
}]);
```

I insert /angularjs/1.4.2/ and /1.4.2/angular-cookies.js

I got these errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
at new <anonymous> (app.js:4)
at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4452)
at $get.P.instance (angular.js:9001)
at S (angular.js:8111)
at g (angular.js:7543)
at g (angular.js:7547)
at angular.js:7418
at angular.js:1635
at n.$get.n.$eval (angular.js:15848)
at n.$get.n.$apply (angular.js:15947)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12332$get @ angular.js:9111$get.n.$apply @ angular.js:15949(anonymous function) @ angular.js:1633e @ angular.js:4452d @ angular.js:1631Ac @ angular.js:1651Zd @ angular.js:1545(anonymous function) @ angular.js:28361m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.js:3148m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.js:3260m.extend.ready @ jquery.js:3472J @ jquery.js:3503
```

Comment: You have to inject $http.

Comment: where i have to inject it

Comment: when i change second line like this 
app.controller('menusCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$cookies',function($scope, $http, $cookies)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or something for us?

Comment: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UJzlET3l2OqITpQucbAD?p=preview)  this is sample from my code its works fine at the beggining but when i try to get cookies its crash

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.mybasket = JSON.parse($cookies.get('mybasket'));
$cookies.put('mybasket',JSON.stringify($scope.mybasket));
```

i'v use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

add $**scope** and $**http** to the parameters of your controller as :

```
app.controller('menusCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$cookies',function($scope, $http,$cookies) {
...
}])
```